# Need to regenerate downloadable_link_purchased entry for customer

Tags: magento-1.9, downloadable, download-link

We had a downloadable product that was set up incorrectly (the actual PDF we were selling wasn't linked to the product).  Somehow a customer bought the mis-configured product but now over in their "My Downloads" area they aren't showing an entry for the product.  We went back and linked up the PDF correctly, but now there doesn't seem to be an entry in downloadable_linked_purchased for this customer.

Is there a way to regenerate that link for our customer so that it will show up in their "My Downloads" area?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I had to do to get the link to show up again.  Since the downloadable link is created at purchase I had to simulate an order.  In the admin I went to the customer and created an order for them with the product.  I then did a custom price on the product to make it free and sent it through.  Now I have a link for the product in the "My Downloads" area.  This process needs to be done for each customer that bought the product when it wasn't linked up correctly.